# Month and Day of sometimes interchange when being inserted to the database

Tags: c#, sqlite, t-sql, xamarin.android, ssms

The date format of the SQL server is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.

The date in SQLite database is formatted as yyyy-MM-dd.

When I want to insert data to the SQL Server, I will be retrieving first the data from the SQLite database and convert it using Convert.ToDateTime of C#.

Most of the time, this conversion is accurate and will insert the correct date to the SQL Server. However there were reports wherein the month and day has interchanged(e.g 2023-12-01 will become 2023-01-12 when inserted in the SQL Server.

I do not have much of an idea how can this be happening. I've searched several times but have not seen any similar issues as this.

I hope I can get some insights from here.

Comment: This is a result of a design flaw in SQL Server dating back decades. When the locale is set to recognize and display DMY "dd/mm/yyyy" dates (most everywhere except the US), someone long ago decided that dates in the form "xxxx-xx-xx" should be interpreted as "year-day-month", instead of (what most would expect) "year-month-day".  This only applies when converting to DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME data types. The newer DATE and DATETIME2 types are not affected. See [this dv<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xt9E9TTI).

Comment: Workarounds: (1) Use DATETIME2 instead of DATETIME. (2) Adjust the dates to eliminate the dashes - "yyyymmdd" will be interpreted as the expected "year-month-day". (3) You can (temporarily) override the day/month ordering with `SET DATEFORMAT YMD` before the import in the same context. (4) If you are importing using a select statement, you can try using an explicit conversion like `CONVERT(DATETIME, imported_date_string, 121)`.   I expect there are other options.

Comment: Was there a way to replicate this scenario? As I mentioned, most of the times, the dates from SQLite to SQL Server were accurate. Also, when this thing happens, a row of data which contains 2 column with the same DATETIME data type will have different values. One is correct and the other is the interchanged month and day.

Comment: Check the column types. If one was DATETIME and the other was DATE, DATETIME2, or VARCHAR, the behavior would be different. If that is not it, take a close look at the literal representations in the import data. Are there subtle differences?  For a better answer, post the precise column definitions of the target table, sample import data that is giving you problems (mixed results), and describe the mechanism or tools you are using to import the data. (Your import tool might have specific date format settings, or it might try to guess based on the first few rows of data.)

Comment: TN's comment is interesting but the DB fiddle demos that SQLS is doing the string to date conversion, yet you (CodeX) claim that C# is doing the conversion. Think it's time you showed us the code

Comment: I did several tries and found the two columns of SQLite differs in format. The 1st one has a format of yyyy-MM-dd while the other one has MM-dd-yyyy. Both of them will be converted to C# DateTime object before passing it to SQL Database as a parameter in INSERT QUERY. Upon checking, the dates appears to be the same. I was really wondering if the interchange happens rarely and randomly. I can't show you the code atm because I am asking through my phone. I will create a similar code later as I cannot disclose it.

Comment: It may be the case that your C# runtime current culture settings are such that your `Convert.ToDateTime()` calls are recognizing `yyyy-mm-dd`, but may be interpreting your `MM-dd-yyyy` date strings as `dd-MM-yyyy`. Perhaps you can look at using [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact), which allows you to explicitly specify one or both formats expected for each date/time column conversion.